# Mathematical formulation of correspondence analysis?

Tags: correspondence-analysis

From [a website](http://yatani.jp/HCIstats/CA)

> you can think that Correspondence Analysis is a categorical data
>   version of PCA. But the main usage of Correspondence Analysis is
>   different from that of PCA, and it is more like clustering or Factor
>   Analysis. With Correspondence Analysis, we can analyze and visualize
>   the relationships among your observed data, and see which parts of the
>   data are associated with another part of the data.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis) also says

> It is conceptually similar to principal component analysis, but applies to categorical rather than continuous data. In a similar manner to principal component analysis, it provides a means of displaying or summarising a set of data in two-dimensional graphical form.

But I don't understand [its details process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis#Details), because I don't know what kind of problem Correspondence Analysis is trying to solve? Is there a clear mathematical formulation of the problem?

Comment: The kinship of simple CA with PCA is considered quite thoroughly in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/141754/3277. See also there a link to answer by @chl

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Stata documentation](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/mvca.pdf#mvca) for CA (even if you're not a Stata user):

> Correspondence analysis offers a geometric representation of the rows
>   and columns of a two-way frequency table that is helpful in
>   understanding the similarities between the categories of variables and
>   the association between the variables.

There are lots of examples, references chosen for  clarity, and the math can be found on page 20.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an $I\times J$ contingency table $C$ with elements $C_{ij}$ and total number of observations $n=\sum_i\sum_j C_{ij}$.

Simple $K$-dimensional correspondence analysis models this as
$$
\frac{C_{ij}}{n} = \alpha_i\beta_j(1 + \sum^{K}_k\mu_i\sigma_k\nu_j)
$$
You *can* think of this as a particular geometrical decomposition of a table of proportions, as described in the Stata documentation linked to by @dimitriy-v-masterov.  This equation is the final equation in that document, despite being probably the most useful one to have started with.

Personally, I prefer to think of CA as a least squares approximation to the $K$ dimensional log multiplicative 'association' model of $C$:
\begin{align}
C_{ij} \sim &~  Poisson(\mu_{ij})\\
\mu_{ij} = &~ \alpha_i^* + \beta_j^* + \sum^{K}_k\mu_i^*\sigma_k^*\nu_j^*.
\end{align}
This makes it a bit  clearer that the goal of both models is to create an interpretable low dimensional model of the table's association structure - that is, the variation in counts that should not be expected under independence.  Increasing $K$ changes the models' complexity from independence to saturation.

In both models $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ensure the margin counts are captured whereas the elements of the sum exist to model the association structure. In CA the elements in the sum are essentially the first $K$ singular vectors and values of an SVD of the residuals from an independence model of $C$.

Biplots plot variously scaled $\mu$ or $\mu^*$ and $\nu$ or $\nu^*$ in the same space. Confusingly, some people refer to such plots as CA rather than the first model.

Comparisons of either model to factor analysis are basically unhelpful.  From a measurement perspective these models model proximity, or 'ideal point' item structure, rather than a dominance structure of factor analysis.