# how to solve weighted low rank approximation problem with diagonal weight matrix

Tags: svd, linear-algebra

Without weights the low rank approximation problem can be solved in terms of svd of the original matrix.But is there any way to solve the problem following problem

$$\min_C{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^d (N_{ij}-C_{ij})^2\sigma_j^{2}}$$
in terms of svd of N?

N is the original matrix.C is the low rank approximation.I need to find the low rank matrix C such that the above function is minimized.here $\sigma$ s are column wise weights.This a special case of weighted low rank approximation.If all the weights are 1s the we can get a solution based on svd.

Comment: What are all these notations?

Comment: edited the post please have look

Comment: I feel that you may be speaking of weighted (=generalized) SVD which is what is being done in weighted biplot, for example. I recommend you to read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141755/3277) my answer.

Comment: Would it be better to use "column weights" instead of "diagonal weights" in the title?