# It is possible to apply correspondence analysis to a 2x2 contigency table?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, correspondence-analysis

I was wondering if it is possible to apply correspondence analysis to a 2x2 contingency table. Since that correspondence analysis is a method for dimensionality reduction, I think it is necessary to have a contingency table with many rows and columns. Is there a minimum value of the number of rows and columns needed to apply correspondence analysis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Please read paragraphs on Correspondence analysis in http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/141755/3277.) In a 2x2 contingency table since there is only 2 categories on each side profiles are trivial: to have "similar vs distant" profiles you need to have at least 3 categories. Moreover, the number of dimensions of the biplot will be `min(2-1,2-1)=1. Thus, the results are trivial and of no much interest.